# Updating a measure through SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube

I have an already deployed cube.

I want to make a minor change in one measure. Is there a way to edit a measure in an already deployed cube through SSMS?

Comment: Not directly. SSMS has no designer support for cubes, but you can execute the XMLA necessary for changing objects if you generate it through some other means (like changing the cube in your designer, rebuilding the project, locating the XMLA and extracting the dimension definition to put in an `Alter` statement). Overall this is more complicated than just redeploying the cube, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot do that from SSMS, but you can connect to already deployed cube through Visual Studio (you will need SSAS extension), and make the change in the cube and just save it and you should see your changes.